# How to replicate Instagram or Facebook pinch to zoom in and drag gestures on image inside UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, pinchzoom

I'm trying to replicate the **pinch to zoom in** and **drag** of post image just like Instagram and Facebook does and I already achieved this effect but there are two main problems:

1. When zooming, the image in my `UITableViewCell` is sometimes clipped to cell bounds even if `cell.clipToBounds` and `cell.contentView.clipToBounds` are both set to false.
2. My project structure is like this: `UITabBarController` -> `UINavigationController` -> `UIViewController` with an `UITableView` inside. Of course, because of this structure, when zooming and dragging the image inside a cell, it will be clipped also to the navigation bar and the tab bar. 
   What I would like is to be able to do these gestures on fullscreen, not only in parent container (current view controller containing the tableview) like now.

What I've tried so far is to add a subview to `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` in which I add my image to the same coordinates of image inside the cell but relative to the screen frame. 
I'm thinking of a solution when I begin the gestures on the image inside the cell but, after that, how can I pass them to the one added on fullscreen to make the impression that the gesture is continuous?

Are there any other solutions, like making zoom and drag area possible above navigation and tab bars, or opening without animation another view controller which has a scrollView inside, or anything else?

What do you you guys think is the best solution to achieve this? I'm very sure at least one of you wanted to know how to do this at a specific moment.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use this [Library](https://github.com/paulemmanuel-garcia/InstaZoom). Also you can read the code there it's pretty obvious.